# mysql count number of digit appearence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column containing single digit from 0-9.
I need to know how many times each digit appears.
i.e 0-4 times, 1-5 times etc`.

I have 6 column to count from so i dont want to execute 9*6 queries if possible to do in less.

EDIT:

```
col1    col2    col3
 1        2      1 
 2        1      3 
 6        3      8
```

I need to know how many times 1 appeared in column 1, how many times in column 2 and how many times in column 3.
This goes for all the numbers.

thanks,
Danny

Comment: You probably ought to consider normalising your data, so that you store your values in a separate table containing: the FK that identifies your existing record, the column of concern (1-6) and the value contained within it.

Comment: added info for scheme and example

Comment: @eggyal why did you delete your answer? (i.e the perils of NATURAL JOIN: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4545d/7))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have this set of record,

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ COL1 ║ COL2 ║ COL3 ║ COL4 ║ COL5 ║ COL6 ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║    1 ║    6 ║    3 ║    1 ║    2 ║    2 ║
║    2 ║    7 ║    3 ║    8 ║    3 ║    9 ║
║    3 ║    8 ║    3 ║    8 ║    8 ║    9 ║
║    4 ║    9 ║    2 ║    7 ║    1 ║    1 ║
║    5 ║    0 ║    1 ║    3 ║    1 ║    6 ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Query

```
SELECT  a.val, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN colName = 'col1' THEN TotalCount ELSE 0 END) col1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN colName = 'col2' THEN TotalCount ELSE 0 END) col2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN colName = 'col3' THEN TotalCount ELSE 0 END) col3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN colName = 'col4' THEN TotalCount ELSE 0 END) col4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN colName = 'col5' THEN TotalCount ELSE 0 END) col5,
        MAX(CASE WHEN colName = 'col6' THEN TotalCount ELSE 0 END) col6
FROM
        (
           SELECT 0 val UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 2 UNION ALL
           SELECT 3 UNION ALL
           SELECT 4 UNION ALL
           SELECT 5 UNION ALL
           SELECT 6 UNION ALL
           SELECT 7 UNION ALL
           SELECT 8 UNION ALL
           SELECT 9
        ) a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT col1 val, COUNT(*) TotalCount, 'col1' colname 
            FROM tableName 
            GROUP BY col1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT col2 val, COUNT(*), 'col2' colname 
            FROM tableName 
            GROUP BY col2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT col3 val, COUNT(*), 'col3' colname 
            FROM tableName 
            GROUP BY col3
            UNION ALL
            SELECT col4 val, COUNT(*), 'col4' colname 
            FROM tableName 
            GROUP BY col4
            UNION ALL
            SELECT col5 val, COUNT(*), 'col5' colname 
            FROM tableName 
            GROUP BY col5
            UNION ALL
            SELECT col6 val, COUNT(*), 'col6' colname 
            FROM tableName 
            GROUP BY col6
        ) b ON a.val = b.val
GROUP By a.val
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fddf7/16)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ VAL ║ COL1 ║ COL2 ║ COL3 ║ COL4 ║ COL5 ║ COL6 ║
╠═════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║   0 ║    0 ║    1 ║    0 ║    0 ║    0 ║    0 ║
║   1 ║    1 ║    0 ║    1 ║    1 ║    2 ║    1 ║
║   2 ║    1 ║    0 ║    1 ║    0 ║    1 ║    1 ║
║   3 ║    1 ║    0 ║    3 ║    1 ║    1 ║    0 ║
║   4 ║    1 ║    0 ║    0 ║    0 ║    0 ║    0 ║
║   5 ║    1 ║    0 ║    0 ║    0 ║    0 ║    0 ║
║   6 ║    0 ║    1 ║    0 ║    0 ║    0 ║    1 ║
║   7 ║    0 ║    1 ║    0 ║    1 ║    0 ║    0 ║
║   8 ║    0 ║    1 ║    0 ║    2 ║    1 ║    0 ║
║   9 ║    0 ║    1 ║    0 ║    0 ║    0 ║    2 ║
╚═════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Comment: working! how did you do it so fast is beyond me...but it's working :)

Comment: can you please explain this line: "MAX(CASE WHEN colName = 'num1' THEN TotalCount ELSE 0 END) num1,"

Comment: Mysql doesn't have a `PIVOT()` function like any other RDBMS which supports it. So basically it needs to use an aggregate function eg. `MAX()`, *in this case*. The `CASE` test for the value of the column that was generated in the subquery. [Result without aggregate function](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fddf7/17). When the result is *true*, the value given on the column is the aggregated result in the subquery otherwise `0`. So to avoid the repeating value of `val` we then use `MAX()` to aggregate the records.